# check if user input array inside textbox javascript

Tags: javascript

is there a way to check if value of textbox is array
I want this button to show alert indicates if value is array or not 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLPXW.png)

Comment: Could you share the code of what you have tried? This sounds like a work order

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: function check(textboxValue)
{
    if(Array.isArray(textboxValue))
     alert("it is array");
     else
     alert("it is not array");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try?

```
const value = JSON.parse(input.value)
const isArray = Array.isArray(value)
```